# Mysql many to one OR one to many

Tags: mysql, one-to-many, many-to-one

I'm a little confused and need some help on this. I have 3 tables.

User_Works_on

```
+---------+-------------+--+--+
| user_id | project_id  |  |  |
+---------+-------------+--+--+
|    5812 |     1938026 |  |  |
|    6390 |     1938026 |  |  |
|   32088 |     1938026 |  |  |
|   62830 |     1938026 |  |  |
|   64436 |     1938026 |  |  |
|   64441 |     1938026 |  |  |
|   77969 |     1938026 |  |  |
+---------+-------------+--+--+
```

Follower_works_on

```
+-------------+---------+
| follower_id | repo_id |
+-------------+---------+
|       64441 | 1938026 |
|       64441 |  477331 |
|       64441 |  477331 |
|        6390 | 1938026 |
|        6390 | 1529732 |
|        6390 |  477331 |
|        6390 |  477331 |
+-------------+---------+
```

Follows_user

```
+---------+-------------+
| user_id | follower_id |
+---------+-------------+
|    5812 |        6390 |
|    5812 |       10561 |
|    5812 |       37664 |
|    5812 |       51794 |
|    6390 |          58 |
|    6390 |         302 |
|    6390 |        1340 |
|    6390 |        1471 |
|    6390 |        2316 |
|    6390 |        3448 |
|   64441 |       40399 |
|   64441 |       57411 |
|   64441 |       64111 |
|   64441 |      180542 |
|   64441 |      294196 |
+---------+-------------+
```

The table `User_works_on` show the projects which a user works on. `Follower_works_on` shows the projects which a follower works on. `Follows_users` shows which users are followers of others. I want to link two projects if an id is a follower any user. i.e i want to create a link between the project the user works on and the project the follower works on supposing there is a follower relationship between them.

For example:

User 5812 works on project 1938026 
Follower 6390 works on project 1529732 
Follower 6390 follows User 5812 
Therefore there is a link between project 1938026 and 1529732.

I'm new to mysql so i'm not sure how to frame this kind of relationship. Any ideas would be great.

A result would look like this

```
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| User_id | project_id1 | project_id2 | Follower_id |
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    5812 |     1938026 |     1938026 |        6390 |
|    5812 |     1938026 |     1529732 |        6390 |
+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Formatting hint: Code blocks or formatted tables can be laid out nicely with a fixed-width font by highlighting them and `ctl-k` or using the `{}` button in the editor toolbar.

Comment: Can you post a sample output table as the query result would be given the input tables you provided? It would help to know what columns you need in the query output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT project_id, repo_id
FROM User_Works_on AS u
JOIN Follows_user AS fu ON u.user_id = fu.user_id
JOIN Follower_Works_on AS f ON fu.follower_id = f.follower_id
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85b8b1/1)